# Hibernate: use backticks for MySQL but not for HSQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, hsqldb

A project I work on (which uses Java, Spring, Hibernate) recently changed from Oracle to MySQL. There are a few cases where some of the properties in the code are reserved words in MySQL, such as "release".

There are a few solutions, 1) rename properties in the code and subsequent getter/setter methods, also update code that invokes those methods 2) annotate the property in the code with @Column(name="`release`"). This tells hibernate to quote the name when talking to the database.

I'd prefer to stay away from the first approach to reduce the chance of breaking more stuff. The second approach is "ok", except it becomes MySQL specific. In our dev. setup we use HSQL which doesn't like the backticks around those column names.

I looked at the org.hibernate.mapping.Column class and I see it has "getQuotedName" methods that I could potentially override if I could subclass Column and tell Hibernate to use my own Column class.

What's the best way to resolve this issue based on the preferred approach of a) not having to refactor the codebase (b/c of changing property names, getter/setter methods, etc) and b) wanting the app to still work in HSQL and MySQL.

It would be reasonable to have a property in properties file that could be toggled to switch on/off some Column naming fix. Which reminds me, I tried using a custom naming strategy and overriding the "columnName" method to surround the column name in backticks...this doesn't work, even on MySQL.

Comment: Apparently there is a new property hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers (http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4453) that could be used (as of hibernate 3.5 I believe) but s not documented (http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5673).

This isn't an option for me since I am using Hibernate 3.3

Comment: I just answered your question, and I didn't know about this one. This is the first time I see that a question is more correct than the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back ticks solution sounds good. But if it does not work or you do not want to use an undocumented feature of an specific JPA providery: Why don't use column names that are not reserved in any(or the most common) databases at all.

You don't need to change the name of your java properties, you must only specify a column name for them.

Comment: Good point...that's easy enough. I do like having the property names match up with the column names in the db but it's not a requirement and I can rename the column name in the DB to obviously be very close to the Java property name.

Answer (score 0):

Use backtips. It is your way of telling Hibernate that you want that identifier to be quoted properly. It's just a coincidence that backticks are also used as quoting character for MySQL. This backtick will be translated to whatever is the quoting character for your database. Regarding adding quotes as the default behavior, I'm not sure Hibernate have such option. Nothing in the documentation mentions a possible option, and I don't remember seeing anything like this in the test suite as well. But I don't think it's a good idea, as "reserved keywords" are exceptions, not the rule.

Comment: So I should add @Column(name="`....`") to any property that is a reserved word in my code?

I tried using the naming strategy and overriding the "columnName" method to prepend and append backticks to column names but it complains, even in MySQL with an exception such as:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Same physical column represented by different logical column names: foobar.`thing_id` => '`thing_id`' and 'thing_id'

Comment: Yes, @Column(name="``something``") is the usual approach. I would suspect that changing the naming strategy could work too and that this error you are seeing is a bug, but I would need to debug it further to confirm. In any case, it seems you found a property to globally quote all identifiers. That would be a solution too.

Comment: Yes that property to globally quote identifiers might work if I was using Hibnerate 3.5 or newer, but I'm stuck at 3.3 for now. I'll try the @Column. I did write a Python script to check all of the column names in the SQL DDL to see if they use reserved words and it looks like I only have a single column that's an issue right now, so maybe refactoring code in this one case wouldn't be bad, since Hibernate appears to have a better approach (e.g. use the global property) when using a newer version.